# MongoDB: use createCodecProvider generically

Tags: mongodb, scala, generics, typeclass, codec

Instead of having one hard-coded line per case class

```
  val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(
    fromProviders(
      classOf[CaseClassNameGoesHere],
      ...
    ),
    ...
    )
```

I would like to create a method that could create them instead.

Both

```
  def method[T] = {
    Macros.createCodecProvider[T]()
  }
```

and

```
  def method[T: ClassTag] = {
    Macros.createCodecProvider[T]()
  }
```

... give me scala.ScalaReflectionException: type T is not a class

I would hope that the compiler could look at every invocation of this method and do its thing.

Is there a way of accomplishing that? Solutions "far away" from this approach will still be accepted as long as I don't have to create that list of `classOf`s.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just end up with more code, and more complex code, no?  When you pass `classOf[Foo]` to `fromProviders`, there's actually just an implicit `createCodecProvider` that takes a `Class[Foo]` and creates a `CodecProvider` for it. You're still going to have to "manually" pass all the codec providers into `fromProviders`, regardless of how you generate them.  i.e. you'd still end up with something like:

```
val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(
  fromProviders(
    method[Foo],
    method[Bar],
    ...
  )
```